# Error occurring when trying to compare two .txt images in C++

Tags: c++, image, matrix, heap-memory

As part of my University assignment we are required to compare two images in the form of .txt one is the normal image, the other is a jumbled version of the image.

Both images are 512x512 and we are asked to consider that they have been broken into 16x16 blocks which means each block is 32x32.

To compare the two images i'm using a sum of squared differences algorithm on blocks of the image. Starting from the top left and working my way round until an appropriate math is found. However this is where my issue is occurring, after successfully taking a single block from the unjumbled image and comparing it to another block from the jumbled image, the second iteration causes the following error:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Assignment1.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   Assignment1.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

My question is what is causing the error in my code?

The following is my header file called Matrix.h it converts the 2d matrix obtained from the txt file to a 1d image.

```
#pragma
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

class Matrix
{
protected:
    int M;
    int N; 
    double* data;
    Matrix(){M = 0; N = 0;data = 0;}                                                //Constructor to avoid error

public:

    Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data);                               //Constructor
    Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC);
    ~Matrix();                                                                      //Destructor
    Matrix(const Matrix& existingMatrix);                                           //Copy Constructor
    double get (int i , int j)  const;                                              //Returns value at specified location
    const void set(int i, int j, double& val);                                      //Changes value at specified location
    int getM() const;                                                               //Return value of M
    int getN() const;                                                               //Return value of N
    Matrix getBlock(int startRow, int endRow, int startColumn, int endColumn);      //Return section of Matrix
    Matrix operator + (const Matrix& B);
    Matrix operator = (const Matrix& B);
    Matrix operator - (const Matrix& B);
    Matrix operator * (const Matrix& B);
    Matrix operator / (const Matrix& B);
    Matrix operator ++ ();
    double operator () (int i, int j);
    void out();
    double sum();
};

class BinaryImage
    :public Matrix
{

public:
    BinaryImage(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data, double thresh);
    ~BinaryImage();
    BinaryImage(const Matrix& rhs, double thresh);
    BinaryImage(const BinaryImage& existingBinIm);
    const void set(int i, int j, double& val);
};

#endif
```

This next section is my Main, the method we are using in the case of the error is called shuffledLogo().

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include"Matrix.h"
using namespace std;

void shuffledLogo();
double* readTXT(char* fileName, int sizeR, int sizeC);
void writePGM(char* fileName, Matrix& toWrite, int Q);

int main()
{
    int selection;

    cout<<"Select a program to run:"<<endl<<"1 - Logo Reorganisation"<<endl<<"2 - Where's Wally"<<endl<<"Selection: ";
    cin>>selection;
    cout<<endl;
    switch(selection)
    {
    case 1:
        cout<<"Logo Reorganisation Commencing..."<<endl;
        shuffledLogo();
        break;
    case 2:
        cout<<"Where's Wally Commencing..."<<endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"Selection invalid"<<endl;
        break;
    }

    Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}

//Consructor
Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* inputData)
{
    M = sizeR;
    N = sizeC;
    data = new double [M*N];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
    {
        data[ii] = inputData[ii];
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC)
{
    M = sizeR;
    N = sizeC;
    data = new double [M*N];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
    {
        *(data+ii) = 0;
    }
}

//Destructor
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    delete [] data;
}

//Copy Constructor
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& existingMatrix)
{
    M = existingMatrix.getM();
    N = existingMatrix.getN();
    data = new double[M*N];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
        {
            int k = ii*N+jj;
            data[k] = existingMatrix.get(ii,jj);
        }
    }
}

//Pass by constant value
double Matrix::get (int i , int j)  const   
{
    int k = i*N + j;
    return data[k];
}

//Pass by Refrence
const void Matrix::set(int i, int j, double& val)
{
    int k = i*N + j;
    val = data[k];
}

//Return Value of M
int Matrix::getM() const
{
    return M;
}

//Return Value of N
int Matrix::getN() const
{
    return N;
}

//Return Section of the Matrix.
Matrix Matrix::getBlock(int startRow, int endRow, int startColumn, int endColumn)
{
    int Row = endRow-startRow;
    int Column =  endColumn - startColumn;
    double* block = new double[(Row)*(Column)];
    int n = endColumn-startColumn;
    for (int ii = startRow; ii < endRow; ii++)
    {
        for (int jj = startColumn; jj < endColumn; jj++)
        {
            int k = ii*n+jj;
            block[k] = data[ii*N+jj];
        }
    }
    Matrix t(Row,Column,block);
    delete [] block;
    return t;
}

//Allows for addion of Matricies, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator +(const Matrix& B)
{
    Matrix C = Matrix(M, N, 0);
    double temp;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
        {
            temp = data[ii*N+jj] + B.get(ii,jj);
            C.set(ii,jj, temp);
        }
    }

    return C;
}

//Makes x and y equal, Opperation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator =(const Matrix& B)
{
    if (this == &B)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    else 
    {
        M = B.getM();
        N = B.getN();
        delete [] data;
        data = new double [M*N];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
        {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
            {
                data[ii*N+jj] = B.get(ii,jj);   
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
}

//Allows for subtraction of matricies, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator -(const Matrix& B)
{
    Matrix C = Matrix(M, N);
    double temp;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M-1; ii++)
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < N-1; jj++)
        {
            temp = data[ii*N+jj] - B.get(ii,jj);
            C.set(ii,jj, temp);
        }
    }

    return C;
}

//Allows for multiplication of Matricies, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator *(const Matrix& B)
{
    Matrix C = Matrix(M, B.getN());
    double temp;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
        {
            temp = data[ii*N+jj] * B.get(ii,jj);
            C.set(ii,jj, temp);
        }
    }

    return C;
}

//Allows for addition of Matricies, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator /(const Matrix& B)
{
    Matrix C = Matrix(M, B.getN(), 0);
    double temp;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ii++)
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < N; jj++)
        {
            temp = data[ii*N+jj] / B.get(ii,jj);
            C.set(ii,jj, temp);
        }
    }

    return C;
}

//Incrmentation of all values in Matrix by 1, Operation Overloading.
Matrix Matrix::operator ++()
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
    {
        data[ii] = data[ii]++;
    }

    return *this;
}


//Allows calling of "get" function indirectly.
double Matrix::operator() (int i, int j)
{
    return data[i*N+j];
}

double Matrix::sum()
{
    double total = 0.0;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
    {
        total = total + data[ii];
    }


    return total;
}

void Matrix::out()
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
    {
        if(data[ii] == 255)
            cout<<"1 ";
        else
        cout<<data[ii]<<" ";
    }
}

BinaryImage ::BinaryImage(int sizeR, int sizeC, double*input_data, double thresh)
    :Matrix(sizeR, sizeC, input_data)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
    {
        if (data[ii] > thresh)
        {
            data[ii] = 1;
        }

        else 
        {
            data[ii] = 0;
        }
    }
}

BinaryImage::BinaryImage(const Matrix& rhs, double thresh)
    :Matrix(rhs)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii < M*N; ii++)
    {
        if (data[ii] > thresh)
        {
            data[ii] = 1;
        }

        else 
        {
            data[ii] = 0;
        }
    }

}

BinaryImage::BinaryImage(const BinaryImage& rhs)
{
    M = rhs.getM();
    N = rhs.getN();
    data = new double[M*N];
    for (int ii = 0; ii<M; ii++){
        for (int jj = 0; jj<N; jj++){
            data[ii] = rhs.get(ii, jj);
        }
    }
}

const void BinaryImage::set(int i, int j, double& val)
{
    int k = i*N + j;
    val = data[k];
}

void shuffledLogo()
{
    char* filePath2 = "E:\\logo_shuffled.txt";
    double* basIm2 = readTXT(filePath2, 512, 512);
    Matrix logoWithNoise(512, 512, basIm2);
    cout<<"done"<<endl;

    //Reads in the Shuffled Image
    char* filePath = "E:\\logo_shuffled.txt";
    double* basIm = readTXT(filePath, 512, 512);
    Matrix logoShuffled(512, 512, basIm);
    cout<<"done"<<endl;


    Matrix logoUnshuffled(512,512);
    double Score = 0.0;                                                     //Current "Pixels" score
    double bestScore = 0.0;                                                     //Best "Pixel" score
    int bestX, bestY = 0;

    //For Loop to begin Sum of Squared Differences
    for (int x = 0; x < 480; x+=32)
    {   
        for (int y = 0; y < 480; y += 32)
        {
            Matrix subWithNoise = logoWithNoise.getBlock(x,(x+32),y,(y+32));
            //subShuffled.out();
            bestScore = 70000.0;
            for (int xx = 0; xx< 480; xx+=32)
            {
                for (int yy = 0; yy < 480; yy+=32)
                {
                    //Calculating the Score starts here
                    cout<<"loop started"<<endl;
                    int t = yy+32;
                    int l = xx+32;
                    Matrix subShuffled = logoShuffled.getBlock(xx,l, yy, t);
                    cout<<"submade"<<endl;
                    Matrix diff = subWithNoise - logoWithNoise;
                    Matrix product = diff*diff;
                    Score = diff.sum();
                    if (Score < bestScore)
                    {
                        bestScore = Score;
                        bestX = xx;
                        bestY = yy;
                    }
                    cout<<"loop ended"<<endl;
                }
            }

            //For loop to put the best option into the final Matrix
            for (int ii = bestX; ii < (bestX+=32); ii++)
            {
                for (int jj = bestY; jj < (bestY+=32); jj++)
                {
                    double temp = logoShuffled.get(ii,jj);
                    logoUnshuffled.set(ii,jj,temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Creates file
    char* newFile = "finished.pgm";
    writePGM(newFile, logoUnshuffled, 1);

}

//Reads in file and from specified location and builds it
double* readTXT(char* fileName, int sizeR, int sizeC)
{
    double* input_data = new double[sizeR*sizeC];
    int i =0;
    ifstream currentFile(fileName);
    if (currentFile.is_open())
    {
        while(currentFile.good())
        {
            if (i>sizeR*sizeC-1) break;
            currentFile >> *(input_data+i);
            i++;


        }
        currentFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"File path not found"<<endl;
    }

    return input_data;
    delete [] input_data;

}

void writePGM(char* fileName, Matrix& toWrite, int Q)
{
    int x = toWrite.getM();
    int y = toWrite.getN();
    unsigned char *image;
    ofstream myfile;

    image = (unsigned char *) new unsigned char [x*y];

    // convert the integer values to unsigned char

    for(int i = 0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<y; j++)
        {
            image[i*y+j]=(unsigned char)toWrite.get(i,j);
        }
    }

    myfile.open(fileName, ios::out|ios::binary|ios::trunc);

    if (!myfile) 
    {
        cout << "Can't open file: " << fileName << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    myfile << "P5" << endl;
    myfile << y << " " << x << endl;
    myfile << Q << endl;

    myfile.write( reinterpret_cast<char *>(image), (x*y)*sizeof(unsigned char));

    if (myfile.fail()) 
    {
        cout << "Can't write image " << fileName << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    myfile.close();

    delete [] image;
}
```

I have taken the liberty of placing my folders in a public dropbox file for you to all see if you'd like to get a better look at the error. I understand that my code might be messy and poorly displayed so if anyone has any suggestions on how to make it better please say.

[Dropbox to program files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f9gtfcdnwzvfkca/v8Olwgn6x4)

Comment: try to run it in your IDE or write a core-file so that you know where it is happening

Comment: So how do 16x16 blocks have dimensions of 32x32?

Comment: Well if the 512 image is split into blocks of 32x32 in size then there are 16x16 blocks created, each block is 32x32.....